# Reopen Oscilloscope Window in Proteus 8

Tags: oscilloscope, proteus

I've installed Proteus 8 and began to work with it. I've built a primitive circuit with oscilloscope. At first time visualization window (with graph of signal) was being got. I closed this window and stopped the simulation. But in the next time this window didn't open.

I try to solve this problem with the help of Google and found the answer: "You must to click right button of mouse at oscilloscope and find "Digital Oscilloscope" and problem will be solved". But it actually works in another versions of Proteus. I didn't find this in Proteus 8.

How to solve this problem in Proteus 8?

Answer (score 28):

In order to show again the closed oscilloscope window start the simulation, then click pause and open the debug menu. From there click the oscilloscope option and the oscilloscope window will appear.
You can then resume or stop and restart the simulation and the window will be visible. The same stands for any other closed debug window.
Using the `Reset Debug Popup Windows` option in the debug menu (enabled only when the simulation is stopped) has a similar effect but the difference is that it will show all closed windows while with the way I describe you can show the selected windows only.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct solution.